# Creating a list of names that cannot be duplicate (if duplicate add number to name)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have an objectList of class Person, which has a Name property. My goal is to end up with a Unique List of names in the end. Any duplicates have to get added with a number at the end of them.

For example lets say the objects that we are looping through have names such as:
John, Mike, Pete, Mark, Pete, Adam, Stan, Pete
My unique list should end up looking like:
John, Mike, Pete, Mark, Pete02, Adam, Stan, Pete03

I am trying to do the following but it will not work the third time Pete goes in:

```
Dim nameList As List(Of String)
Dim uniqueList As List(Of String)
For Each object In objectList
    Dim name = object.Name
        If nameList.Any(Function(str) str = name) Then
            name = name + "02"
        End If
    nameList.Add(object.Name)

    uniqueList.Add(name)             
Next
```

Comment: What does will not work mean? what does it do the third time?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Dim result = names.GroupBy(Function(x) x) _
               .SelectMany(Function(x) x.[Select](Function(v, i) New With { _
                           Key .Value = v, Key .Index = i}) _
               .Select(Function(z) z.Value + (If(z.Index <> 0, 
                                           (z.Index + 1).ToString(), [String].Empty))))
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H7WBBU).

`C#` Equivalent:-

```
var result = names.GroupBy(x => x)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Select((v,i) => new { Value = v, Index = i })
                .Select(z => z.Value + (z.Index != 0 ? (z.Index+1).ToString() 
                                                     : String.Empty)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
name = name + "02"
```

with

```
name = name & (uniqueList.Count(Function(str) str Like name & "*") + 1).ToString()
```

The latter counts the occurrences of Pete* (= Pete, Pete02 and so on) in the uniqueList and therefore knows what number to append. Take caution: If you have e.g. "Pam" and "Pamela" in the list, the next Pam will get number 3 as "Pamela" starts with "Pam" as well.

Comment: I am getting an error saying uniqueList.Count takes no parameters.

Comment: Did you reference `System.Linq`?

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ :

```
Dim namesList = New String() {"Pete", "Mary", "Pete", "Pete"}

Dim namesListUnique = namesList.Select(Function(item, index) New With { _
    .OriginalName = item, _
    .Index = index _
}).Select(
    Function(item) 
        Dim nbBefore = namesList.Take(item.Index).Count(Function(i) i = item.OriginalName)
        Dim uniqueName = item.OriginalName
        If nbBefore > 0 Then
            uniqueName &= (nbBefore + 1).ToString("00")
        End If
        Return uniqueName
    End Function _
).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a dictionary to store the number.

```
    Dim namesList = New String() {"John", "Mike", "Pete", "Mark", "Pete", "Adam", "Stan", "Pete"}
    Dim uniqueList As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    For Each name As String In namesList
        Dim uniqueName As String

        uniqueName = name

        If Not uniqueList.ContainsKey(name) Then
            uniqueList.Add(name, 1)
        Else
            uniqueList(name) += 1

            uniqueName &= uniqueList(name).ToString("00")
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(uniqueName)
    Next
```